# Dynamically load svgs as components in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, components

My issue is basically this:
I have a bunch of svg images all stored in a .js file like this

```
import React from 'react'

export const React = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="#c90016"/></svg>

export const Angular = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="#c90016"/></svg>

export const JQuery = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="#c90016"/></svg>
```

in another component I want to render correct image based on an array, so for instance I have:

```
import {React,Angular,JQuery} from '../svgs'
const images = [
    'React','React','JQuery','Angular','JQuery'
]
```

no I want to render each image, actually to do something like this

```
<div>
images.map (image => <image>)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make some changes in `svgs.js` as you are exporting a named constant `React` again so it will throw duplication error when you import it.

```
import React from 'react'

export const react = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="#c90016"/></svg>

export const angular = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="#c90016"/></svg>

export const jQuery = () =>
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><ellipse cx="238.456" cy="39.252" rx="28.346" ry="26.522" fill="green"/></svg>
```

After that import them where you want

```
import {react, angular, jQuery} from '../svgs'

// don't use quotes as it represents string
// const images = [
//   'react', 'angular', 'jQuery'
// ]

const images = [
    react, angular, jQuery
]
```

And last use them in jsx

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
     // use uppercase letter for React component 
     {images.map((Image, index) => <Image key={index} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```